# Editing size of image without loosing its quality and dimensions

Tags: adobe, photoshop

I have a image with size of 5760 x 3840px with size of 1.14mb. But I would like to reduce its size to 200 kb by not changing the dimensions of the image. How Could I do this using photoshop? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on a large format file size that has a resolution of 300 dpi. If the image is 5760 x 3840, your canvas size will be 19.2 x 12.8. in order to not "reduce" the dimension (printable area) you are going o have to reduce the `image size` [ALT + CTRL/CMD + I] and then reduce the resolution from there.

At 300 DPI:
[image]

At 72 DPI:
[image]

This reduction in resolution can decrease the file size dramatically, There is a chance of artifacts, but as you are starting at a high resolution the compression algorithms will smooth it out to almost non-existent.

NOW... If you are *starting* at 72dpi and you are looking for a good way to generate a lower file size for the web, your best bet may be to do a `Safe for web` option [ALT + CTRL/CMD + SHIFT + S] and generat a .jpg, .gif or a .png based on the final needs of the file. If it is an photograph with a lot of colors, I would go .jpg. If you have a lot of areas of solid color (logo perhaps) I would go with .png or .gif.

[image]

The Save for Web option allows you to see, side by side, the results of the export BEFORE going through the save process. it also allows you to alter the settings of the save process to dial in your results. best of all, it gives you a pretty good preview of the expected file size.

Either way this should help you save that larger file size for future use.